# CKEDITOR - <p> instead of <br/> causing copy-paste issues

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Some time ago I changed the CKEDITOR to not use `<br>` tag and use `<p>` instead. This makes things alot easier for me.

But today I spotted a problem here... When I paste into ckeditor this text:

> Text
>
> More text

CKEDITOR makes this: `<p>Text</p><p>More text</p>`. How can I configure ckeditor so that it will put put only single `<p>` tag over whole text, and inside it will put `<br/>`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration option for pasting itself. You can, however, change behaviour of entire CKEditor if you set [`config.enterMode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config) to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`. Then CKEditor will not use paragraphs at all. On the other hand, it's not recommended to use other enter modes, because the default (`CKEDITOR.ENTER_P`) is the most correct, semantic and best supported.

Although, if you must change the paste behaviour, there's one more way. You can listen to [`editor#paste`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) event and transform content in your preferred way. Very rough implementation would look like this:

```
editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
    var data = evt.data.dataValue;
    data = data
        .replace( /^<p>/, '' )
        .replace( /<\/p>$/, '' )
        .replace( /<\/p><p>/g, '<br />' );
    evt.data.dataValue = data;
} );
```