# django-ckeditor: how to make carrige return insert a <br> instead of a new <p>?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

In my CKEditor instances, I need ENTER to insert a `<br>` instead of a new `<p>` element, mainly because of the line separation. I found [this question](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Line-Breaks) in the CKEditor forums and gave it a try (although they talk about fckconfig.js and not config.js), but it didn't work. Also found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436417/ckeditor-p-instead-of-br-causing-copy-paste-issues), but I don't know how to apply the solution.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can change `ckeditor` configs. There are two options for changing this config:

**a- 1 for adding `<p>` tags for enter mode**

**b- 2 for adding `<br>` tags for enter mode**

So you can use this configs in your project's `settings.py`:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'enterMode': 2, # 1 for add p tags and 2 for add br tags
    },
}
```

Therefore I think you should use `2` as your enter mode option.

Comment: I forgot to ask. Where can I get a list of these configuration attributes (like `enterMode`)? I don't see a lot of them [here in the docs](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I found `enterMode` somewhere, but it wasn't related to `django-ckeditor`, just `ckeditor`, so it said to set it to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`, which wouldn't work; the `2` didn't appear anywhere to me. There are also other configuration attributes that I'd like to get in an extended list.